# connecting with Derby from within the java application

Tags: java, database, database-connection, derby

this program works fine when i connect the java db under the 'Services' tab in netbeans but when i try to open the executable jar file of the prog outside neatbeans it doesn't work at all. I want this java application to be accessible by multiple users as i wish to put it on the my local network so i figured that i need to connect to the Derby database in network mode....am i correct.?.....how should i fix this..?following is code snipet of my application

```
 public void DoConnect() {
    try {
        /*
         **  Load the Derby driver. 
         **     When the embedded Driver is used this action start the Derby engine.
         **  Catch an error and suggest a CLASSPATH problem
        */
      Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        try {NetworkServerControl server = new NetworkServerControl();
        server.start (null);}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(driver + " loaded. ");
    } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("\n    >>> Please check your CLASSPATH variable   <<<\n");
    }

    try {
        //CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employee";
        String uName = "admin";
        String uPass = "admin";

        //EXECUTE SQL QUERY AND LOAD RESULTSET
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Workers";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        //MOVE CURSOR TO FIRST RECORD AND GET DATA
        rs.next();
        int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
        String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
        String first_name = rs.getString("First_Name");
        String last_name = rs.getString("Last_Name");
        String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

        //DISPLAY THE FISRT RECORD IN THE TEXT FIELD
        textID.setText(id);
        textFirstName.setText(first_name);
        textLastName.setText(last_name);
        textJobTitle.setText(job);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: after adding the first try catch block when i rebuild the project the....the jar file of the application is not even starting.......

Comment: What do you mean by "not even starting"? Does it throw an exception? The exception contains a lot of information: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: @BryanPendleton with the above code when i try to run the executable jar file outside netbeans nothing happens at all.....if i remove the first try catch block then i get the Jframe i created when i run the jar file but  without any connection to the Employee database i created using netbeans services.......both with or without the first try catch block the code works fine in netbeans environment....

Comment: @BryanPendleton please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it is bad practice to use a Derby database in network mode **and** to start the server in the same application. You combine all weaknesses of both world :

- you cannot access the database from the outside (you server has to be local)
- what happens if you server is allready running (if multiple executions on same node) ?

I think it works fine under Netbeans, because Netbeans is doing all the housekeeping for you : starting the server when you access to it via Netbeans interface, and closing it when closing Netbeans.

I think you should try the folowing :

- start a server (manually) from outside of your application
- remove the code for launching server from your app

(and do not forget to stop server when you have finished with it ...)

By the way I cannot understand what you mean by "not even starting" : if you start it from command line, you should have at least an error message ...

Comment: I am developing the application in java so which database server would be best ( considering that the server should be easy to handle on localhost as i new to working with databases ). By "not even starting" i meant that i tried to open the file by double clicking it instead of opening it from command line.....

Comment: If it is a simple application, you can use Derby in network mode ... as long as it is started outside the application. If you need a first class database, Mysql, MariaDB or postgreSQL are well-known open databases. But when testing a java app **always** starts it from command line so you can give error messages to potential helpers :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written the program there is no reason to meddle with the services tab. You should be able to just run (debug) the program directly in NB. Set a breakpoint, debug and step through it. When that works you can try to run from the command line.